# finite non-abelian groups with all proper subgroups cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian group which all proper subgroups of $G$ are cyclic. I want to know, this forces $G$ has exactly one prime divisor?

Comment: Not quite. $G$ could also have order $pq$ for suitable primes $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Dear Tobias Kildetoft, If $G$ is a $p$-group such that $\vert \Omega_1(G) \vert =p$, then this forces $G$ can not consists of a non-cyclic subgroup, is it correct?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by consisting of a non-cyclic subgroup here. If $|\Omega_1(G)| = p$ (i.e. $G$ has a unique subgroup of order $p$) then either $G$ is cyclic or $p=2$ and $G$ is generalized quaternion.

Comment: Ok, If $G$ is non-cyclic, $G$ must be $Q_8$?

Comment: Yes, as long as we still assume all proper subgroups to be cyclic (as this property is not one the other quaternion groups have).

Comment: So in this case, if $G$ has a non-cyclic subgroup, then $G $ is not isomorphic to $Q_8$, ok?

Comment: Well, a proper one. But yes, all proper subgroups of the order $8$ quaternion group are cyclic.

Comment: Please update the question with all these details so that they are easier to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest counterexample is, I think, $G=S_3$. Every proper subgroup has order $2$ or $3$, hence is cyclic. Nevertheless $S_3$ is non-abelian and its order is divisible by two different primes.

Comment: At least it's hard to find a smaller counterexample :)